# oracle Listagg query issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute the query with listaggand regex.Its giving me an error..

```
PRODUCT      DESCR            PRENBR      PREDESCR            dependies
101400      karupm           3213         oaera              1234 SW AND 3213 W
101400      Simple           234          samp               1234 SW AND 3213 W
101401      Opsim Op SW      3534         SimPilo            1595 SW OR 3533 SW AND 3534 NS
101401      Opsim Op SW      3533         Eldo Ap            1595 SW OR 3533 SW AND 3534 NS
101401      Opsim Op SW      1595         AccuSim II         1595 SW OR 3533 SW AND 3534 NS
```

Comment: And what might that error be?  Those of us who lack the ability to read minds might be interested.

Comment: Error is "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what error you are receiving, but I might guess that it's a `GROUP BY` error.  You are selecting `part.part_nbr` in your statement, but then grouping by `part.part_id`.

Try changing your `GROUP BY` to:

```
GROUP BY part.part_nbr
```

Or, if you need to group by both:

```
GROUP BY part.part_id, part.part_nbr
```

Comment: Cool.I'm refering your previous example only.

Comment: @user2444474 -- I knew that code looked familiar!  When using `GROUP BY`, make sure the fields in your `SELECT` list are also in your `GROUP BY` list.  You can leave them out in other databases, but not in Oracle.

Comment: I'm trying to constructive new query which using liastagg as per another change.My output format is different ..

Comment: I have added original query which trying change